# Java's equivalent of [self performSelector:foo afterDelay:2]

Tags: java, android

i am developing an android app
i need to go from one activity to another
in that first i need to change the colors of button then a delay (so that the) and then call this same function(the one i am in rite now)

in objective-c it is done with  [self performSelector:foo afterDelay:2]

so i need to the its java equivalent.

Answer (score 9):

For delayed actions in Android I'd recommend using the Android [`Handler` class](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/os/Handler.html) with its [`postDelayed()` method](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)).

Create a handler for your `Activity` as a member variable:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

And then add your delay action as follows:

```
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
            //Do you thing here
        } 
    },2000);
```

Comment: Note that you don't necessarily need a Handler for this if you do not already have one. `postDelayed()` is also available on any widget (e.g., `Button`).

Comment: Does the run() function execute on the same or a different thread than the class in which it was invoked? If different, is there a way to make it run in the same thread?